# Form validation only works on first row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my password validation code but it is only working for the first row. Can anyone help me to make it work on all rows including the newly added row?

```js
var password = document.getElementById("password")
confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function validatePassword() {
  if (password.value != confirm_password.value) {
    document.getElementById("confirm_password").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("confirm_password").style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
}
```

Comment: It only works on the first row because you're using `id` attributes, and they ***have*** to be unique to each element. To do what you require you will need to use common class attributes on the elements and then loop through them all to validate them.

Comment: Unrelated piece of advice: indicating validity with color only (red or green) fails accessibility guidelines. See [Understanding Success Criterion 1.4.1: Use of Color](//www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/use-of-color.html).